# How can you make a method which can change one parameter at time for every parameter?

Tags: java, class, methods

How can you make a method (only 1) which is able to change every parameter of a object? And you can chose only one parameter at a time.

Well, my idea is this. I got a object, with 3 variables (for example, object(first,second,third) ) and I want to change object first parameter, second and third...

Okay, I know how to make method which changes one parameter at a time (but then i need to make 3 methods or 4, if i want to make a method which asks for all 3 parameters.) e.c., but is there a way to make only 1 method, that can do it all for every parameter? for example...

```
 double count(object.)  /*After the point you can input which 
 parameter you want to change. Method asks only for 1 object parameter,
 but you can use this method for every parameter of the object. */
    {
      return object. +19;
    }
```

and when i want to call the method I can do something like this

```
 count(object.first)
 count(object.second)
```

and you can do it all with only one method. I really don't know how to explain it very well.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this cannot be done (without reflection) unless you store all your attributes in a `Map<String, Object>` which I highly recommend you not to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) to get the instances of Member, but this is heavy and slow. I'd prefer a `HashMap<String, AtomicInteger>` :

```
public class MultiCounter {
    private Map<String, AtomicInteger> counters = new HashMap<>();
    public synchronized int count(String name) {
        AtomicInteger c = counters.get(name);
        if (c==null) {
            c = new AtomicInteger(0);
            counters.put(name, c);
        }
        return c.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Being a little more sophisticated, you could also define an enum for your key :

```
enum Key {
    first,
    second
}

private Map<Key, AtomicInteger> counters = new EnumMap<Key, AtomicInteger>(Key.class);
public synchronized int count(Key key) {
    AtomicInteger c = counters.get(key);
    if (c==null) {
        c = new AtomicInteger(0);
        counters.put(key, c);
    }
    return c.incrementAndGet();
}
```

This would allow

```
 int count = myCounter.count(Key.first);
```

Comment: Who says all of his attributes are numeric type? I understand his question like this: 'How do I replace all setters with one method, that can modify a given attribute of my class, so that when I add an attribute I don't have to add another setter?'

Comment: @jlordo I infered that from the count method. But I'm not sure I get all what is implied in the question.

Answer (score 0):

if these parameters are objects and no primitive types like int or double, then you just can pass them into your method, change their attribute's values and leave it (you don't need to return anything). your calling method will be able to work with these changes. your parameters are passed by value (that means the object you pass will be copied and your method is working with a new copy) but their attributes still link to the same area in your memory (that means the attributes of your object do have the same reference to the memory as the attributes of your object's copy).

```
public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        MyObject param1 = new MyObject();
        MyObject param2 = new MyObject();
        MyObject param3 = new MyObject();

        setCountUp(param1, param2, param3);

        System.out.println(param1.getCount());
        System.out.println(param2.getCount());
        System.out.println(param3.getCount());
    }

    private void setCountUp(MyObject param1, MyObject param2, MyObject param3) {
        param1.setCount(param1.getCount() + 1);
        param2.setCount(param2.getCount() + 2);
        param3.setCount(param3.getCount() + 3);
    }

    private static class MyObject {
        private long count = 1;

        public void setCount(long count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        public long getCount() {
            return count;
        }
    }
```

result will be:
2
3
4